# How to install and run an official Bitcoin wallet on Ubuntu?

Tags: wallet, installation

That's probably very noob question, but I am new in Bitcoin and cannot find clear help. I downloaded Linux Bitcoin wallet from the official page, its name is `Bitcoin-com-wallet-3.6.0-linux64.tar.gz`. I want to just install it and run, but after unpacking I found many executable files and no `README`. Instructions found on the web write about `./autogen.sh` and
`./configure` files, but I cannot find it there neither. What should I do?

Comment: Just to clarify, Bitcoin.com is not "the official page of Bitcoin", it is a for-profit project controlled by a controversial figure in the Bitcoin community. Bitcoin is a distributed opensource project, thus there is no "official" wallet, but you can find an overview of various wallets here: bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this package is official `Bitcoin-com-wallet-3.6.0-linux64.tar.gz`. I suggest you to download from https://bitcoin.org. There are several wallet programs for desktop, web, mobile, etc. [Here is an list.](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet)